# How to emulate telephone channel 8k speech given 16k microphone speech recording

Tags: signal-processing, speech-recognition, telephony, audio-processing

I have a task of emulating 8k landline/cellular/VoIP speech audio given 16k microphone recording of that speech. What are the main stages for emulating it? I've found [this](https://pytorch.org/audio/main/tutorials/audio_data_augmentation_tutorial.html#simulating-a-phone-recoding) torchaudio tutorial on such augmentation, and it is the most detailed instructions on how to do it.

Finaly I see following 16k mic -> 8k tel conversion pipeline:

1. 16k -> 8k resampling
2. Applying RIR (room impulse response to simulate reverberations) [OPTIONAL]
3. Applying noise [OPTIONAL]
4. Applying sox compand filter (is it needed? what other parameters might be used?)
5. Apply codecs (GSM, g72*, SILK, OPUS, etc.)

What should be added? Equalization, some special filters, packet loss concealment emulation? May be there is existing Matlab scripts or libs for such augmentation?

Comment: because resampling from 16k to 8k is solved easily, you can reduce your question to: how to emulate the transfer function of a  telephone channel. 
or going from 8k row audio to 8k after phone channel.

Comment: @Kings85 thanks, you are right it is a bit messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a wave file

```py
from scipy.signal import lfilter, butter
from scipy.io.wavfile import read,write
from numpy import array, int16

def butter_params(low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = low_freq / nyq
    high = high_freq / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_params(low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def apply_telephony_effect(f1, f2):
    fs,audio = read(f1)
    low_freq = 300.0
    high_freq = 3000.0
    filtered_signal = butter_bandpass_filter(audio, low_freq, high_freq, fs, order=6)
    write(f2,fs,array(filtered_signal,dtype=int16))
```

you can create another

```py
apply_telephony_effect('input.wav', 'output.wav')
```

The output will sound like telephone.